# How to create a VPN connection when "New Connection Wizard" hangs at "Network Connection Type" and the Rasman service fails to start with error 1075?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, vpn

A Windows XP Professional SP3 machine fails to create new VPN connections using "Control Panel" > "Network Connections" > "New Connection Wizard".

The "New Connection Wizard" stops at the page "Network Connection Type", which asks for "What do you want to do?". Selecting any of the 4 options does not result in being able to progress any further when pressing the "Next" button.

The "Remote Access Connection Manager" (Rasman) service is configured with "Startup Type: Automatic", is not started, and fails to start when doing so manually:

> Could not stat the Remote Access Connection Manager service on Local Computer.
>   Error 1075: The dependency service does not exist or has been marked for deletion.

How to fix this to become able to set up a new VPN connection?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the string "`Tapisrv`" (which is a not existing service) from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\DependOnService`
2. Copy rasman.dll, rasmans.dll, rasppp.dll, raschap.dll, rastls.dll to C:\WINDOWS\System32\ (from another Windows XP machine)
3. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\PPP\EAP` and delete entries other than 13, 25, and 26. The entry that was deleted was named "4".
4. Apply http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/regs_edits/remoteacm.reg
5. Reboot
6. Again, delete the string "`Tapisrv`" (which is a not existing service) from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\DependOnService`
7. Reboot

Presto, the "**Remote Access Connection Manager**" now starts without **error 1075** and the "**New Connection Wizard**" continues beyond the "**New Connection Type**" question.